# JSON response not assigned to textfield text

Tags: json, extjs, sencha-touch-2

When i call the Method,JSON response not assigning to the textfield ,Here i mentioned through the id. But its not assigning to the text field text.

**JSON response**

[image]

**Method**

```
function viewgiftdetails(itemid,p,t) {
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : 'http://192.168.1.155:8181/WishList/ShowItemsByItemID/userID=3/itemID=19',             
    method: "GET",
    useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
    withCredentials: true,
    success: function (response) {
        var respObj = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
        Ext.Msg.alert("Success", respObj[0].itemName);
        Ext.getCmp('myitemname').setData(respObj[0].itemName)
        Ext.getCmp('myitemdesc').setData(respObj[0].describe)
        Ext.getCmp('myitemprice').setData(respObj[0].price)
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
}
```

**PANEL**

```
   var viewitemspnl = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
                                         id: 'viewitemspnl',
                                         scrollable:'vertical',
                                         height: '100%',
                                         width: '100%',
                                         items: [{
                                                 xtype: 'toolbar',
                                                 ui:'light',
                                                 docked: 'top',
                                                 title: 'My items',
                                                 items: []
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                 xtype: 'textfield',
                                                 name : 'itemName',
                                                 id:'myitemname',
                                                 label: 'Item Name',
                                                 useClearIcon: true
                                                 },
                                                 {
                                                 xtype: 'textfield',
                                                 name : 'itemdesc',
                                                 id:'myitemdesc',
                                                 label: 'Description',
                                                 useClearIcon: true
                                                 },
```

Whats wrong with my code?PLease help to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should not be

```
 Ext.getCmp('myitemname').setData(respObj[0].itemName);
```

Because their is no any method **setData()** for the textfield.

> Try this

```
Ext.getCmp('myitemname').setValue(respObj[0].itemName);
```